# Como ”Pegar" o valor da variável COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT?

Tags: php, bash, composer

Estou usando um script `bash` para definir a variável `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT`, mas antes de mudar o valor dela eu preciso saber qual é o valor que está definido.

Dei uma boa olhada na internet e não encontrei nada similar, nem mesmo na documentação do Composer.

Definindo um novo valor para `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT`

```sh
    setComposerProcessTimeout(){
        echo "Defining the COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT = 2000"
        composer --global config process-timeout 2000
    }
```

Como pegar o `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT` e usar ele como no script abaixo:

```sh
    COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE = #(Não sei como pegar o valor).

    if !${COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE} == 300 ; then
      echo ${COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE}
    fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou deixar a solução aqui para ajudar caso alguém precise

Consegui pegar o valor usando o comando abaixo:

```sh
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT_VALUE=$(composer --global config process-timeout)
```

E então poderei usar no if como por ***exemplo***:

```sh
setComposerProcessTimeout() {

    if [[ "${COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT_VALUE}" != "2000" ]]; then
        echo "Defining COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT to 2000"
        composer --global config process-timeout 2000
    fi
    exit
}
```

Assim eu consigo pegar e comparar a variável e redefinir ela se for preciso.